# Need this message to animate for 10 seconds Ext.info('Saving', 'Saving your changes...')

Tags: extjs

I really need help since i can't figure it out please. In a website i am using extJS library and it works if i add 10 seconds delay on showing the message.

SCENARIO:

In Admin section, User clicks save button and the ext displays a message "Saving your changes" using this command "Ext.info('Saving', 'Saving your changes...')" . This message displays for 2/3 seconds only and i need it to be there for 10 seconds.

I have tried myself and can't figure out how/where to change it.

Anyone please help...

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.Msg.wait('Saving', 'Saving your changes...', {
    duration: 10000
});
```

With that said, why make the user wait for 10 seconds arbitrarily? I hope there's a **very** good reason for that...

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, But maybe look for a `setInterval("code()", 3000)` or `setTimeout("code()",3000)` and change it to `10000`

Answer (score 0):

you could also try the following:

```
Ext.Msg.wait('saving tables to disk...','File Copy');
window.setTimeout(function(){
   Ext.Msg.hide();},10000)
```